# Sqlbuddy show very slow responsetimes

Tags: php, mysql, sqlbuddy

i don't know if this is the right place to ask a question but i'm going to try anyway...

I was looking for a leightweight alternative of phpmyadmin and found sqlbuddy. Very good performance at first an very customizable.

However, since a few days it became very slow on login and just as slow with some insert functions. So the first thing i did was to place a fresh download in a new folder. Same issue...

I am not good with sql and php so what i am looking for are some tips and tricks to check some stuff.

First of all, is there a way to see what takes so long to logon. A logon in phpmyadmin on the same server runs smoothly on hostgator. Or can it be that the database is not on the same server wich causes the delay? When i use a website analyzer it tells me the fage load good but it onky loads the login form so that is no help.

The website itself has decent performance but every now and then it tells me too many connections when i have no connection at all. When i look in the phpadmin status is see between 100-120 connection but is that my current connection and normal behaviour?

Other custom scripts i use to connect and read data perform good so everything points to sqlbuddy for me.

I get the errors below...

```
        [08-Sep-2013 05:14:07 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: magickwand: Unable to initialize module
        Module compiled with module API=20060613
        PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
        These options need to match
         in Unknown on line 0
        [08-Sep-2013 05:14:07 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
        Module compiled with module API=20060613
        PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
        These options need to match
         in Unknown on line 0
        [08-Sep-2013 05:14:07 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mailparse: Unable to initialize module
        Module compiled with module API=20060613
        PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
        These options need to match
         in Unknown on line 0
        [08-Sep-2013 05:14:07 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: PDO: Unable to initialize module
        Module compiled with module API=20060613
        PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
        These options need to match
         in Unknown on line 0
        [08-Sep-2013 05:14:07 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module
        Module compiled with module API=20060613
        PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
        These options need to match
         in Unknown on line 0
        [08-Sep-2013 05:14:07 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/sqlite.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/sqlite.so: undefined symbol: third_arg_force_ref in Unknown on line 0
        [08-Sep-2013 05:14:07 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
        Module compiled with module API=20060613
        PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
        These options need to match
         in Unknown on line 0
        [08-Sep-2013 05:14:07 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: uploadprogress: Unable to initialize module
        Module compiled with module API=20060613
        PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
        These options need to match
         in Unknown on line 0
        [08-Sep-2013 05:14:07 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module
        Module compiled with module API=20060613
        PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
        These options need to match
         in Unknown on line 0
```

I hope someone can show me the right direction...